# Making a Chrome extensions with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, plugins

i started to make a Chrome extension by jQuery and it runs but when i make an event like

```
$("#button").click(function(){
   $("#result").text("Hello World");
});
```

it's printing Hello World but disappers after a less then a second **"SOOO FAST!!"** 
so guys what's the problem ?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code in question.  I would suggest that something else is changing the text, as the above code will not do what you have explained.  It would just show "Hello Wolrd" [sic] and then stop.

Comment: Thank you so much , i just found out that when i submit form jQuery i didn't type "return false" .. so whenever i submit it's refreshing the page in the extension

Comment: That makes sense.  Glad you found it :)

Comment: `return false` is not the more important. `ev.preventDefault()` is.

Answer (score 0):

If your `#button` is an `<a>` tag or submit button and you click it the page is going to change unless you cancel it's default behavior.

```
$("#button").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#result").text("Hello World");
});
```